# Twitter is sleeping issue

Tags: html, css, api, twitter, widget

I have a site that uses a twitter plugin to collect most recent posts however, twitter is displaying the text "twitter is currently sleeping".

Got the client to add new posts as I thought one solution could have been that the client hadn't put up a new post for a few weeks. They added a new post and I still get this issue

[image]

Have googled and researched this online and cannot find anyone that has come into this issue before.

Comment: twitter is sleeping, try a little later

Comment: Thanks for your constructive comment

Answer (score 1):

hey similar problem here.

sometimes they update their widgets and plug-ins and don't let the old ones continue to work. the sleeping might suggest that it will wake up soon though! Just to be safe I would maybe try to use something newer from twitter.com. annoying, aye?

Comment: Very annoying! Thank you for helping - may have to go and find something new.

Comment: check these out friend! http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/10_twitter_list_widgets_you_can_grab_embed_right_n.php